# std::sort_heap in descending order

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

So I came across this code. The only thing I added was the predicate parameter.

```
template<class RandomAccessIt, class Predicate = std::less<>> inline
void heap_sort(RandomAccessIt first, RandomAccessIt last, Predicate predicate = Predicate())
{
    std::make_heap(first, last);
    std::sort_heap(first, last, predicate);
}
```

Now as the title says, it works fine with:

```
int arr[] = { 143, 2, 365, 4, 5 };
heap_sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

But gives me a debug error (invalid heap) with:

```
int arr[] = { 143, 2, 365, 4, 5 };
heap_sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::greater<>());
```

I also tried this with other containers. What is the point of allowing a custom UnaryPredicate then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::make_heap
```

needs to be called with the same predicate:

```
std::make_heap(first, last, predicate);
std::sort_heap(first, last, predicate);
```

Otherwise, the heap is built with the wrong criterion and will not be a max heap with respect to `predicate`. This violates the precondition for `std::sort_heap(first, last, predicate);`.